# NPN Transistor 2N2222 fixed bias MULTISIM

Tags: power, transistors, electricity, multisim

I have been working on my school projects and I wanted to ask you if there is any way of editing BETA for transistor. When I click on transistor, Edit Model is not working. Anyone help me, please.. I have been trying to figure this out for hours..

[image]

Comment: you'll have to come up with your own (modified) model.

Comment: and how to make my own modified model? Well, it would suffice just to know what the BETA itself is. I can't find it there.

Comment: You'll find that not all transistor models give you the \$\beta\$ directly; you'll have to understand the model you want to modify!

Comment: is there an 2n2222.cir file?  with parameters inside?  Does Multisim include the non-linear hFE Vce(sat) vs Ic/Ib and Rce value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this.
[image: Multisim Options Disabled]
Under Options > Global restrictions > General

[image: Multisim Options Enabled]

Red Arrow - Edit Model - It's all you need to check.

Blue Arror - Edit DataBase - I'd leave this checked.

All unchecked and you can do whatever you want.  This may be dangerous for an educational setting.  Plus passwords may be in place.

[image: Options disabled]